# Cambiar el idioma de inglés a español las gráficas de Google charts

Tags: javascript, charts

El código pertenece a una grafica de gantt en Google charts en la cual necesito cambiar los meses a español o ponerlo en días pero igual que este en español.

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
      data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
      data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

      data.addRows([
        ['2014Spring', 'Spring 2014', 'spring',
         new Date(2014, 2, 22), new Date(2014, 5, 20), null, 100, null],
        ['2015Autumn', 'Autumn 2015', 'autumn',
         new Date(2015, 8, 21), new Date(2015, 11, 20), null, 0, null],
        ['2015Winter', 'Winter 2015', 'winter',
         new Date(2015, 11, 21), new Date(2016, 2, 21), null, 0, null],
        ['Football', 'Football Season', 'sports',
         new Date(2014, 8, 4), new Date(2015, 1, 1), null, 100, null],
        ['Baseball', 'Baseball Season', 'sports',
         new Date(2015, 2, 31), new Date(2015, 9, 20), null, 14, null],
        ['Basketball', 'Basketball Season', 'sports',
         new Date(2014, 9, 28), new Date(2015, 5, 20), null, 86, null],
        ['Hockey', 'Hockey Season', 'sports',
         new Date(2014, 9, 8), new Date(2015, 5, 21), null, 89, null]
      ]);

      var options = {
        height: 400,
        gantt: {
          trackHeight: 30
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la [Documentacion](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale) se especifica esto mediante el uso del atributo `language`,en su ejemplo se establece como:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'ja'});
```

Al parecer Google Charts usa por default la configuracion regional `en`